# Indexing an attribute of the elements of an array of another array in a jsonb field

Tags: postgresql, index, json

I have the following document that is stored in a jsonb field in a postgres 11 DB.

```
{
    "bundles": [
        {
            "id": "9c9c1b73-b058-3f22-a48b-725ce39eb861",
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "6645c9e2-b87a-445e-96d8-585240a73b0b",
                    "reservation_id": "4ca47003-c1b2-4b11-9623-7d27a6af8bbd",
                    "source_stock_location_id": "c8ec143a-b311-4d28-80d4-a5d42e6ff7fe"
                }
            ],
            "specification": {
                "customer": {
                    "segment": "D",
                    "priority": 42
                },
                "export_between": {
                    "latest_exclusive": "2019-12-20T10:39:22.427Z"
                }
            },
            "is_part_of_split": false
        }
    ]
}
```

We have now the use case to query the get the row that contains a certain item by id. An example of a simple full scan query would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *, jsonb_array_elements(jsonb_array_elements(event->'bundles')->'items')->>'id' elem 
  FROM bundle
) AS items 
where elem = '6645c9e2-b87a-445e-96d8-585240a73b0b';
```

where `event` is the field containing the jsonb and `bundle` the name of the table.

This is a very expensive query and we are investigating about the possibility of creating a proper index.

We have struggle a bit with it and so far we have come to the following proposal:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bundle_items(jsonb)
  RETURNS jsonb AS
$func$
   SELECT a->'items'
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements($1) a
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

CREATE INDEX items_idx ON pdh.bundle_load_test USING GIN(bundle_items(event -> 'bundles'));
```

which works pretty ok with a query like:

```
select * 
from bundle 
where bundle_items(event -> 'bundles') @> '[{"id": "4ca47003-c1b2-4b11-9623-7d27a6af8bbd"}]';
```

Now the question is if this could be improved, the query pattern would strictly query by id, so just indexing the ids of the items would be enough. But so far I couldn't figure out a way to just index the id.

Comment: You don't need the function, `where event -> 'bundles' @> '[{"id": "9c9c1b73-b058-3f22-a48b-725ce39eb861"}]'::jsonb` will work just fine with a index on `event -> 'bundles'`. But as long as you have the array, you can't index individual IDs directly. That's the price you pay for de-normalizing.

Comment: Are the arrays in your JSONB always going to have a length of 1?  If not, you should pick an example which demonstrates the case where the length is not 1.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm interested in querying for the `id` of the item which is contained in the `event -> 'bundles' -> 'items'` and it seems to me that this double indirection is not directly supported.

Comment: `create index on the_table using gin ( (event -> 'bundles')`